# SwiftUI - Toggle inside a List or Form has to be tapped twice to trigger

Tags: ios, list, forms, swiftui, toggle

I'm not sure what is the cause, but on the first launch of the app I noticed that I need to tap the toggle twice before it can change its state. This happens every first launch of the app.

This problem doesn't occur if I had done something else with the view first, for example by pulling down the list. Naturally, if I don't put the toggle inside a list, it also behaves as normal.

Tested on: iOS 16, both in simulator and real device

Here's a simple reproducable example of the problem

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAdvancedOptions = false
    @State private var enableLogging = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section {
                Toggle("Show advanced options", isOn: $showingAdvancedOptions.animation())

                if showingAdvancedOptions {
                    Toggle("Enable logging", isOn: $enableLogging)
                }
           }
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and if you click anywhere on the screen before clicking on the toggle button and then click the button, you only need to click the button once.

I also changed the List to VStack and then it's only necessary to click once on the button (without clicking on the screen before). So this seems to have to do with List and when you click the first time, it simply is selecting somehow the List.

This code makes the button automatically selected, so you only need to click once:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var showingAdvancedOptions = false
    @State private var enableLogging = false
    @State var id: Int? = 1

    var body: some View {
        List(selection: $id) {
            Section {
                Toggle("Show advanced options", isOn: $showingAdvancedOptions.animation())


                if showingAdvancedOptions {
                    Toggle("Enable logging", isOn: $enableLogging)
                }
           }
           .id(id)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it but the issue still remains. Another thing I noticed on real device, after the first launch of the app, if I close the app from the task manager and reopen it again the toggle behaves like normal (only need to click once). Seems like at first launch the list is causing this weird bug.

Comment: I made a minor change, it should work now.